# Deploy WAR file in XAMPP using Batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, xampp, war

I am using a War file to deploy my application in Xampp. The thing is that since I update the code multiple times I need to replace the war file and restart the Apache, tomcat services. I thought of using a batch file for this to save time.

I'm doing the following 3 steps to deploy a war file.

1) Stop Apache & Tomcat services.

2) Delete existing war file and it's corresponding folder.

3) Start Apache & Tomcat services.

**Batch Script**..

```
   echo "+++Deploy source in $PWD+++"

   echo "+++ Shutting down tomcat ..."
   call apache_stop.bat
   call catalina_stop.bat
   timeout 5 > NUL


   echo "+++ Installing new war ..."
   DEL "C:\xampp\tomcat\webappss\flsv2*"
   xcopy /s C:\Users\Hp\git\flsv2-lucy\build/flsv2.war C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps


   echo "+++ Starting up tomcat ..."
   call apache_start.bat
   call catalina_start.bat
   timeout 5 > NUL
```

Unfortunately the above code is not working. Whenever I run the above script from the xampp folder I'm getting an error message in cmd prompt..

**Error Message**...

```
    C:\xampp>deploy_local.bat

    C:\xampp>echo "+++Deploy source in $PWD+++"
    "+++Deploy source in $PWD+++"

    C:\xampp>echo "+++ Shutting down tomcat ..."
    "+++ Shutting down tomcat ..."

    C:\xampp>call apache_stop.bat
    pv: No matching processes found
    Mysql shutdowm ...
    pv: No matching processes found
    "+++ Starting up tomcat ..."

    C:\xampp>
```

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that strike my eye:

1. `$PWD` is linuxstyle. Use `%cd%` in Windows batch files for the same thing.
2. Maybe you want to add `@echo off` as first line in your script to prevent the double echo-ing of each line to console.
3. The error message "pv: No matching processes found" comes from `apache_stop.bat`. You need to trace/debug that script for further details. (You might want to add a `@echo on` in the first line to get every output).
4. Your output shows no sign of the deleting operations ("Installing new war"), I wonder why but suspect the errors popping up from `apache_stop.bat`. However, the output from the "Starting up tomcat" is there. Is the delete part working as expected? Do files get deleted?
5. Hint: If you use `del` with wildcards (`*`) you can/need to specify the `/Q` switch to prevent the confirmation prompt. See `del /?` on the command line for details.
   Also on `del`, you might want to use `*.*` to get "any filename followed by any extension". Currently with the single asterisk the `del` command is looking for filenames "beginning with flsv2 with no extension". The asterisk wildcard is handled differently by Unix/Linux and Windows.
6. Recommendation: The `xcopy` command should have the paths quoted (mandatory if your paths contain spaces).